# Regular expression query/replacement - Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a set of HTML, where I am looking to scan for each instance of "img src" and replace the value of "src", which is in this instance "cid:ii_151afcf74cab7d3b" with a variable. The content of "src" will vary for each instance. How would I do this with a regular expression?

```
<img src="cid:ii_1w1afcd4cab7d3b" alt="Inline image 1" width="517" height="291">
```

Comment: `html.gsub(/img src="[^"]*"/, "img src=\"#{var}\"")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do interpolation in regular expressions just like you can in strings and symbols:

```
str = 'foo<img src="bar" alt="Inline image 1" width="517" height="291">'
src = /<img src="#{src}" alt="Inline image 1" width="517" height="291">/

str =~ src #=> 4
```

**Edit:** I forgot that since you are looking to replace, you will need to use [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/String.html#method-i-gsub)/[`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) or if you want to do something fancy, maybe [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/String.html#method-i-scan)

Answer (score 2):

**Expression:**

`/(?<=src=")([^"]+)/` will match your `src` content without the `"` sign

`(?<=src=")` is positive look-behind, will match but not take into consideration

`([^"]+)` match anything except `"`, it will match everything you throw at it inside that your `src="will_match_whatever_except_double_quotes"`

[Live](https://regex101.com/r/mR7lT4/1)